# SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Product (in target 'Product' from project 'Product')

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to include Tap To Pay on iPhone functionality in Cordova Plugin, after including the plugin in my Ionic project and trying to build, I get this error eventually:

```
d/sharedpch -pch-disable-validation -module-name Product -frontend-parseable-output -disable-clang-spi -target-sdk-version 16.1 -parse-as-library -o /Users/mads/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Product-anlvmriclbyybqfhfhbdkszgzqql/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Product.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Product.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVTapToPay.o -index-unit-output-path /Product.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Product.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVTapToPay.o -index-store-path /Users/mads/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Product-anlvmriclbyybqfhfhbdkszgzqql/Index.noindex/DataStore -index-system-modules

/Users/mads/company/2/menon/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99. (in target 'Branch' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Product (in target 'Product' from project 'Product')
(1 failure)
Command finished with error code 65: xcodebuild -workspace,Product.xcworkspace,-scheme,Product,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/mads/company/2/menon/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/mads/company/2/menon/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/mads/company/2/menon/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:136:25)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:999:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:266:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build ios --verbose exited with exit code 65.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +2ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 65) +62ms
```

Comment: which plugin are you using to add this functionality? does your app build successfully without the plugin and only fail with the plugin?

Comment: Yes, it compiles without the plugin. will update the latest error in question.

Answer (score 0):

It says it in your error log

```
 The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.1.99
```

Just change your target, in your config.xml

```
   <preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0" />
```

Comment: I changed IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 12.0 but I see few compilation errors and finally the error in question's heading. These are more to do with Tap To Pay on iPhone Structures. Will update the question.

Comment: If the app compiles without the plugin and fails with the plugin, I don't expect changing anything in your config.xml will resolve your issue. The issue is inside the plugin.